# How to send data from HTML to database ( update the referenced object through thymeleaf)?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, save, thymeleaf

I'm making a simple java web app using spring boot and thymeleaf, it's about calculating the total amount of food's calories you eat.

In controller , i created a method like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aaw4c.jpg . This is User class code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsSVX.jpg . In the correspond HTML file https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPiE8.png , I want whenever clicking a button X, user.sumcalo will be added 10 (for example) -> how can i do it? Can i do it by using javascript. Can you give me some suggestions?

Expected user.setSumcalo(calo) works ( like this js code in above html file:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/znxJZ.png ) , but it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

First, it would be more convenient if you post your code here as code and not as an image.

Second, I think your question is too broad, I mean, you can do it with javascript, with jquery, angular, from your backend (java), and they all have pros and cons.

How big is your food catalogue? If it is too big (like MyFitnessPal), maybe you want a little service using an AJAX call to get the possible food and values from DB and handle the sum of your user calorie intake, the list of foods added, and some other stuff on javascript. Finally when the user saves the food intake you can againg use an AJAX call to a service that updates your DB.

The functionality you ask for can easily be achieved an onClick to your button, and then calling a function to do the logic (summing calories, etc.)

Hope this helps you!

Edit: Assuming you have everything well configured, you need to recieve the web request on Java and use some JDBC to connect to a DB and save the updated info. Once you achieve that, make sure by checking the database to see if the info is actually updated.

Comment: Thank you. I did use javascript to do the addition; however, when i turn off the project ( I use intellij IDEA), the turn on, that user calories turn back to 0 ( the database doesn't change). P.s: my database is small.

Comment: Can you give me some tutorial webs to solve the problem (I'm newbie)

Comment: I don't see any code that would increment sum of calories (sumcalo field in User entity).

Comment: #mvmn sorry my bad, actually i did write the code but it wasn't success, user X's sumcalo will turn back to 0 when i re-run the project. Could you give me some tutorial webs to handle this issue, I want my user X's calo to be added 10 when i click some button.

Comment: Oh, silly me, just save the object in Controller class - Problem solved.